# With the Windows SAM and SYSTEM files, can I get the password of an account?

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, backtrack, hashing

I heard of John the Ripper, Ophcrack and many other programs that are used in order to crack the hashes for Windows' 7 Password, but JTR seems a bit slow (Didn't get the password after 20 minutes) and Ophcrack needs rainbow tables, which are hard to find. What you recommend? Thanks.

NOTE: I have access to the physical computer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to uncover the password, as opposed to just removing it or changing it?  I ask, because there are multiple utilities available that will allow you to boot the machine outside of the installed OS, and simply remove the account password.

Comment: I need the password. That's it.

Comment: Actually, the fact that you need the password has already been expressed in the question.  Being redundant and simply stating that again doesn't actually answer the question on whether there is a specific reason as to *why* you need the password.  Of course, I didn't actually ask you for that specific reason... just whether or not there was one.  At this point though, because you seem to be avoiding this line of questioning, I feel promoted to ask you why you NEED the password... or rather, why simply removing the password does not solve your issues?

Comment: I'm gonna make it simple for you: the password that is in that SAM file is the same password for another login in a website. When I say I need the password, I don't mean I need to crack into the system deleting the password or gaining access to certain files. Means that I need the password. <_< read.

Comment: You didn't make it simple for me... or anyone else.  I had to piss you off, and post two comments before you finally came up with this as your reason.  Making it simple would have meant providing this in the original question.  And, as you expressed in the comment to the answer that included Cloudcracker, you don't need the password, you apparently want to gain password cracking knowledge.  Again... you don't need the password itself.  And, why don't you just use the "lost password" function for that website login?  Depending on the site, they might send you the old password.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't just want to brute force the password, it may be worthwhile paying for CloudCracker - https://www.cloudcracker.com/

You can upload the NTLM hashes there and get them to perform the crack. That said, this means you are handing over the passwords for your machine.

Comment: Well that's a good way to do it, but I'd like to learn how to crack it. Brute-forcing is an option although of the time. What program exactly could I use to crack those and what parameters should be used? Thanks a lot for the CloudCracker thingy :P